# DAO 3.6 and Win7/Vista UAC issue

Tags: database, vb.net, uac, dao

I'm using old DAO 3.6 to connect Access database (with mde extension). App works fine on XP and on Win7/Vista when UAC is low/disabled. But when UAC is on I get following error:

*The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file 'C:\ProgramData\company\db.mde'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.*

My code:

```
'Connect to Database
dbE = New DAO.DBEngine()
dbT = dbE.OpenDatabase(Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) & "\company\db.mde")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Access databases are opened read-write. Also by default, regular users don't have write permissions on `C:\ProgramData`. Since, when UAC is enabled, you are just a "regular user", it won't work. To fix this, you have the following options:

- Start your VB.NET application with administrative privileges (Right mouse button/Run as administrator).

or

- Change the NTFS permissions on `C:\ProgramData\company` so that regular users may modify files.

or

- Open the database in **shared read-only** mode. That way, DAO does not require write permissions to the file (*readonly*), nor does it require permissions to create an ldb file (*shared*).

  ```
  dbT = dbE.OpenDatabase(Environment.GetFolderPath( 
      Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) & "\company\db.mde", 
      True, True)
  ```

Comment: I didn't know this was a privilege issue. Now I set Everyone permission on this folder at app setup with InstallShield and no problem :).